# combine compute, loop and concat

Tags: macros, spss

I would like to run the following syntax on lots of variables. Thus, I'd like to loop over a bunch of variables.
The syntax is the following:

```
compute v3a_mit = v3a.
recode v3a_mit
   (-9998=2) (sysmis=9).
exe.
```

In this case, however, the syntax only concerns the variable "v3a".I have some other variables (v3b, v3c, v3d...) for which I would like to execute this syntax.

So, the loop should look like this.

```
DO REPEAT X=v3a to v3z
    compute concat(X,'_mit') = X.
    recode concat(X,'_mit')
       (-9998=2) (sysmis=9).
    exe.
END REPEAT.
```

So, within the loop, new variables shall be created which get a new name depending on the variable which is executed in the loop. The "SHIFT VALUES VARIABLE" command would be ideal (with shift=0) but this command cannot be used within a loop. Unfortunately "compute concat(X,'_mit')" does not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CONCAT` is a function for manipulating the values of string variables. So you can't use it for defining a variable name.

However you can make use of the `!CONCAT` function inside of a SPSS macro.

You can use the following macro to recode a set of variables.

```
DEFINE !recodeVars (vars = !CMDEND)
    * for every variable in the 'vars' list do the RECODE INTO command.
   !DO !var !IN (!vars)
      RECODE !var (-9998=2) (sysmis=9) INTO !CONCAT(!var, '_mit').
   !DOEND
!ENDDEFINE.

* macro call.
!recodeVars vars = v3a v3b v3c v3d.
```

Here, I used the `RECODE INTO` command, instead of one `COMPUTE` and a following `RECODE` command. But of course the principle of how to use the !CONCAT command would be the same for the COMPUTE operation.

However you **can't** call the macro in way like this `!recodeVars vars = v3a TO v3z.` In that case the macro would try perform the RECODE for the variables "v3a", "TO" and "v3z". You have to call this macro with the whole list of variables you want to recode.

This might be a lot of typing. As an easy way to avoid the typing, you could produce a SPSS command via the SPSS Menu (for example Analize -> Descreptive Statistics -> Frequencies) Then select the variables you want to recode (select the first variable, hold the SHIFT key and select the last variable) and then press the paste button. The Frequency command with the list of variables will be pasted to your syntax. You can now copy paste the variable list to your macro call.

If you have the Python integration plugin installed you could also use this small python block to retrieve the varlist between two variables.

```
BEGIN PROGRAM.
import spss,spssaux

variables = 'v3a to v3z' #Specify variables
varlist = spssaux.VariableDict().expand(variables)

spss.SetMacroValue('!varlist', ' '.join(varlist))
END PROGRAM.
```

This creates a macro named "!varlist" which expands to the list of variables when called.

You can now call the "!recodeVars" macro the following way: `!recodeVars vars = !varlist.`

If you don't have the python plugin installed (and don't want to use manual typing or copy and pasting) you can get the full variable list with the use of the ["!DefList" macro from Raynald's SPSS Tools](http://www.spsstools.net/Macros/Gems/DefineListOfVariablesBetweenTwoVariables.sps).

---

By the way, you can also make use of a macro for the `SHIFT VALUES` command.